# How can I delete the validation rule appiled to my collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I am trying out the document validators that the database itself provides. Here is the command that I have written

```
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "admin",
  validator: {
    $or : [
      { isActive : { $type : "bool" }},
    ],

    $and: [
      { name : { $type : "string" }},
      { mobileNumber : { $type : "int" }},
    ]
  },
  validationAction: "error",
  validationLevel: "strict"
});
```

So it executed perfectly and I can see it in `getCollectionInfo` command but now I want to delete this rule but I can't find the method to do it anywhere.

How do I delete this ?
Also is there any method which can apply validators to collection which exists as well as non existing collections ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the validation level to `off`

```
db.runCommand({
   collMod: "admin",
   validator: {},
   validationLevel: "off"
})
```

Where `collMod` is the name of your collection

Comment: Yeah I tried this and seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @felix it's important to note why it wasn't working. The database won't correctly copy, or more specifically - write over to the destination db, because there are invalid documents existing in the current one.

Comment: Note `collMod` is the name of the collection to be modified.

Comment: I tried several things like rewriting the validation, turn it off, etc.... and still not working